# Is there a way to use asyncio.Queue in multiple threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
import asyncio
import threading

queue = asyncio.Queue()

def threaded():
    import time
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        queue.put_nowait(time.time())
        print(queue.qsize())

@asyncio.coroutine
def async():
    while True:
        time = yield from queue.get()
        print(time)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.Task(async())
threading.Thread(target=threaded).start()
loop.run_forever()
```

The problem with this code is that the loop inside `async` coroutine is never finishing the first iteration, while `queue` size is increasing.

**Why is this happening this way and what can I do to fix it?**

I can't get rid of separate thread, because in my real code I use a separate thread to communicate with a serial device, and I haven't find a way to do that using `asyncio`.

Comment: `"I can't get rid of separate thread, because in my real code I use a separate thread to communicate with a serial device"` -- Have you tried using `loop.run_in_executor` to do any blocking interaction with the serial device?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`asyncio.Queue` [is not thread-safe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue), so you can't use it directly from more than one thread. Instead, you can use [`janus`](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus), which is a third-party library that provides a thread-aware `asyncio` queue.

```
import asyncio
import threading
import janus

def threaded(squeue):
    import time
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        squeue.put_nowait(time.time())
        print(squeue.qsize())

@asyncio.coroutine
def async_func(aqueue):
    while True:
        time = yield from aqueue.get()
        print(time)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = janus.Queue(loop=loop)
asyncio.create_task(async_func(queue.async_q))
threading.Thread(target=threaded, args=(queue.sync_q,)).start()
loop.run_forever()
```

There is also [`aioprocessing`](https://github.com/dano/aioprocessing) (full-disclosure: I wrote it), which provides process-safe (and as a side-effect, thread-safe) queues as well, but that's overkill if you're not trying to use `multiprocessing`.

**Edit**

As pointed it out in other answers, for simple use-cases you can use [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading) to add to the queue, as well.

Answer (score 22):

If you do not want to use another library you can schedule a coroutine from the thread. Replacing the `queue.put_nowait` with the following works fine.

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(queue.put(time.time()), loop)
```

The variable `loop` represents the event loop in the main thread.

EDIT:

The reason why your `async` coroutine is not doing anything is that
the event loop never gives it a chance to do so. The queue object is
not threadsafe and if you dig through the cpython code you find that
this means that `put_nowait` wakes up consumers of the queue through
the use of a future with the `call_soon` method of the event loop. If
we could make it use `call_soon_threadsafe` it should work. The major
difference between `call_soon` and `call_soon_threadsafe`, however, is
that `call_soon_threadsafe` wakes up the event loop by calling [`loop._write_to_self()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f908005ce16b06d5af7b413264009c4b062f33c/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L626) . So let's call it ourselves:

```
import asyncio
import threading

queue = asyncio.Queue()

def threaded():
    import time
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        queue.put_nowait(time.time())
        queue._loop._write_to_self()
        print(queue.qsize())

@asyncio.coroutine
def async():
    while True:
        time = yield from queue.get()
        print(time)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.Task(async())
threading.Thread(target=threaded).start()
loop.run_forever()
```

Then, everything works as expected.

As for the threadsafe aspect of
accessing shared objects,`asyncio.queue` uses under the hood
`collections.deque` which has threadsafe `append` and `popleft`.
Maybe checking for queue not empty and popleft is not atomic, but if
you consume the queue only in one thread (the one of the event loop)
it could be fine.

The other proposed solutions, `loop.call_soon_threadsafe` from Huazuo
Gao's answer and my `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` are just doing
this, waking up the event loop.

Comment: This worked for me properly. I tested and it's sharing messages between thread and the courutine.

Answer (score 13):

`BaseEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe` is at hand. See [`asyncio` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading) for detail.

Simply change your `threaded()` like this:

```
def threaded():
    import time
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, time.time())
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(lambda: print(queue.qsize()))
```

Here's a sample output:

```
0
1443857763.3355968
0
1443857764.3368602
0
1443857765.338082
0
1443857766.3392274
0
1443857767.3403943
```

Answer (score 3):

What about just using threading.Lock with asyncio.Queue?

```
class ThreadSafeAsyncFuture(asyncio.Future):
    """ asyncio.Future is not thread-safe
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000200/asyncio-wait-for-event-from-other-thread
    """
    def set_result(self, result):
        func = super().set_result
        call = lambda: func(result)
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(call)  # Warning: self._loop is undocumented


class ThreadSafeAsyncQueue(queue.Queue):
    """ asyncio.Queue is not thread-safe, threading.Queue is not awaitable
    works only with one putter to unlimited-size queue and with several getters
    TODO: add maxsize limits
    TODO: make put corouitine
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.waiters = []

    def put(self, item):
        with self.lock:
            if self.waiters:
                self.waiters.pop(0).set_result(item)
            else:
                super().put(item)

    async def get(self):
        with self.lock:
            if not self.empty():
                return super().get()
            else:
                fut = ThreadSafeAsyncFuture()
                self.waiters.append(fut)
        result = await fut
        return result
```

See also - [asyncio: Wait for event from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000200/asyncio-wait-for-event-from-other-thread)

Comment: I like the idea, I have a similar situation where i want a blockin put from a different thread then the asyncio event loop one. Be aware thou, that your snippet does not handle the job_complete correctly. if the awaiting coroutine calls `task_done()` the queue may raise, because it was never notified about an item being in the queue initially (it was directly put into the future).