# Python POST request in functionA, the other function receive it and send it back

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, http, post

I am new to `python` and `HTTP request`, and I am trying to implement HTTP request between two functions, which I am not sure will work. Can you read my thoughts and give me some suggestions/examples on how to implement them?

Here's what I expect:
Let's call these two functions A and B; B is the while true loop, and both A and B are in different threads.

```
When A receive a post request with a body
B will create a txt file in my file system
A will receive the txt file path and write "hello world" into it
```

Is that something I can do with `python` and `HTTP request`. My intutitive thought is I can use thread and lock to implement it, but I am not sure on how to do it. Can you give me some idea or suggestions?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using threading to achieve it ?

Comment: [asyncio: Wait for event from other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000200/asyncio-wait-for-event-from-other-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> some idea or suggestions?

- Use two [Events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) created in the main thread
- One event signals 'B' to make a text file
- The other signals 'A' that a new file has been made
- Probably could make it work with one Event

  - 'A' sets the event then waits/loops till it is clear
  - 'B' waits for the Event to set then makes a file and clears the even
- Use a module level variable in the main thread to *hold* the file name

  - 'B' modifies the variable.
  - 'A' reads the variable.

---

Or

- Use Queue's to send signals and info between threads