# asyncio.Queue.get() gets stuck on empty queue

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

In the following code I have a **producer** running in its own thread and generating **Runnable** objects and putting them in an asyncio.Queue. The **consumer** is running as a task in the ayncio event loop.  Everything works fine as long as the queue is not empty.  **Once the `await queue.get()` encounters an empty queue it never returns even if items are added to the queue**. I am running with python version 3.7.6.

```
import threading
import asyncio
import random
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(0)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-5s| %(name)s: %(funcName)s: %(message)s')
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)


#=======================================================================
class Runnable(object):
    def __init__(self, id, load):
        self.id = id
        self.load = load
        return

    async def run(self):
        logger.info(f"Running: {self.id}, load: {self.load}")
        await asyncio.sleep(self.load)
        logger.info(f"Done Running: {self.id}, load: {self.load}")
        return

    
#=======================================================================
def producer(queue):
    logger.info("Starting producer")
    eventId = 0
    
    while(True):
        eventId += 1
        load = random.uniform(1, 5)
        r = Runnable(eventId, load)
        queue.put_nowait(r)
        logger.info(f"Added runnable. qsize: {queue.qsize()}")
        time.sleep(3)
    return


async def consumer(queue):
    logger.info("Starting consumer")
    while(True):
        logger.info(f"Waiting for runnable. qsize: {queue.qsize()}")
        r = await queue.get()
        logger.info("Received runnable")
        await r.run()
        logger.info("Done with processing runnable")
    return


def main():
    # create and start a producer
    queue = asyncio.Queue(20)
    prodThd = threading.Thread(target=producer, args=(queue,))
    prodThd.start()

    # start consuming on the async event_loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(consumer(queue))
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
    return

#=======================================================================
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
2020-06-26 19:52:13,555 DEBUG| asyncio: __init__: Using selector: SelectSelector
2020-06-26 19:52:13,561 INFO | root: producer: Starting producer
2020-06-26 19:52:13,561 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 1
2020-06-26 19:52:13,561 INFO | root: consumer: Starting consumer
2020-06-26 19:52:13,561 INFO | root: consumer: Waiting for runnable. qsize: 1
2020-06-26 19:52:13,561 INFO | root: consumer: Received runnable
2020-06-26 19:52:13,561 INFO | root: run: Running: 1, load: 1.320570165693137
2020-06-26 19:52:14,882 INFO | root: run: Done Running: 1, load: 1.320570165693137
2020-06-26 19:52:14,882 INFO | root: consumer: Done with processing runnable
2020-06-26 19:52:14,882 INFO | root: consumer: Waiting for runnable. qsize: 0
2020-06-26 19:52:16,562 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 1
2020-06-26 19:52:19,562 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 2
2020-06-26 19:52:22,564 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 3
2020-06-26 19:52:25,565 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 4
2020-06-26 19:52:28,566 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 5
2020-06-26 19:52:31,568 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 6
2020-06-26 19:52:34,569 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 7
2020-06-26 19:52:37,569 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 8
2020-06-26 19:52:40,569 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 9
2020-06-26 19:52:43,570 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 10
2020-06-26 19:52:46,571 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 11
2020-06-26 19:52:49,572 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 12
2020-06-26 19:52:52,573 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 13
2020-06-26 19:52:55,574 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 14
2020-06-26 19:52:58,575 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 15
2020-06-26 19:53:01,576 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 16
2020-06-26 19:53:04,576 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 17
2020-06-26 19:53:07,577 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 18
2020-06-26 19:53:10,579 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 19
2020-06-26 19:53:13,579 INFO | root: producer: Added runnable. qsize: 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to add items to the queue from a completely different thread, outside the event loop. Asyncio queues can only be safely interacted with from within the event loop. They are [explicitly not threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) - quoting the docs:

> This class is not thread safe.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889527/is-there-a-way-to-use-asyncio-queue-in-multiple-threads) For ways to use `asyncio.Queue` from multiple threads.

Comment: Got it. Thanks that helped.