# FastAPI, how to block requests until specific one completes?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

My path operator in FastAPI making API calls.
External API is protected and I have to provide Bearer token in my requests.
In my application I check whether current Bearer token has expired and issue a new token, if so.

For example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


class Token:

    def expired(self) -> bool:
        ...

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        ...


def get_token() -> Token:
    ...


async def issue_new_token() -> Token:
    ...


async def touch_external_api(headers: dict):
    ...


@app.post('/process/{task_id}')
async def handler(task_id):
    token = get_token()
    if token.expired():
        token = await issue_new_token()
    await touch_external_api(headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'})
```

How to ensure that when multiple concurrent requests hit my path operator and `token.expired()` returns `True` only the first one will call `issue_new_token` and others will wait for it to complete? Or how can I ensure that issuing new token will be done only once?
Is preemptive update in the background task seems like a solution?

I'm thinking about using asyncio primitives but it seems hackish and I haven't got an opportunity to test it:

```py
token_lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def issue_new_token() -> Token:
    ...


async def issue_token() -> Token:
    if not token_lock.locked:
        await token_lock.acquire()
        token = await issue_new_token()
        token_lock.release()
    else:
        await token_lock.acquire()  # wait until coroutine whish issues new token releases
        token_lock.release()
        token = get_token()
    return token


@app.post('/process/{task_id}')
async def handler(task_id):
    token = get_token()
    if token.expired():
        token = await issue_token()
    await touch_external_api(headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'})
```

Comment: Your implementation is the only way of going I can think of (without using a database or other external tools). Will you use `uvicorn` or `gunicorn` with multi thread? In case of multi thread, your approach should not work as `asyncio` works on a single thread only. In that case, you'll need a shared state like a database  that can scale (how many users may hit the server with a refresh token?)

Comment: Hi @lsabi!

I'm using Gunicorn with uvicorn workers, single threaded, application is IO bound. 
What comes to loads, I need to handle 2k TPS, in the worst case there might be 2 thousand simultaneous requests which may want to refresh the token.

What comes to scaling and launching multiple workers - new tokens do not invalidate other tokens, so sharing state is not an issue for now, one might think if new tokens do not invalidate older tokens then there is no need in synchronization, but 2K access tokens every hour seem very wrong :^)

Comment: Thinking of moving `issue_new_token` functionality in get_token() and make this function synchronous and blocking on IO. So other coroutines will naturally wait for it to complete.
First request which calls this function will see that token is expired and thus will block the whole app and update the token. Others will be able to call this function only when token is refreshed and will get new, updated token.
Too bad this solution will also block other path operators

Comment: 2k tokens per hour are not normal. What kind of application is it, if I may? At this point, i would use a shared state (possibly a database), which gets updated every hour or so, since several requests can use the same token. That way, you only have one token to generate and maintain.... Hope I got right the usage, as it is not very clear to me

Comment: You got it right @lsabi. It's a marketing application which handles steady stream of user requests, and it's just happen that application need to access external protected API.
I think I came up with a sound solution using asyncio.Queue, will post later, because for now it's only in my head :)

Comment: glad to have helped, though now I have even more doubts on my side... if it's a stream, why use HTTP instead of websockets? If it's multithread then `asyncio.queue` cannot be used. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889527/is-there-a-way-to-use-asyncio-queue-in-multiple-threads

Comment: Because application protocol was build with http in mind, we can't upgrade to websokets as we have not built this protocol :) Application is single threaded

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean "stream" as stream. What I meant is that we're receiving HTTP requests at a constant rate of ~2k per second

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using queues.

The idea here is to create a task in lifespan event handler (asgi app startup) which will handle token refresh requests on `TokenManager` object.

If we need to get a new token - all co-routines will block in `self._out_queue.get()` until background task handles issuing of a new token.
If there is no need in refreshing a token - background task is blocked in `self._in_queue.get()`

So here is my solution with a demo:

```py
import asyncio
import typing
import time
import random
import string


TokenData = typing.TypedDict(
    "TokenData", {"expires_in": int, "access_token": str, "token_type": str}
)


class Token:

    def __init__(self, data: TokenData):
        self.expires_at = time.time() + data["expires_in"]
        self.token_value = data["access_token"]
        self.token_type = data["token_type"]

    def expired(self, c_time=None) -> bool:
        c_ctime = c_time or time.time()
        return c_ctime > self.expires_at

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.token_type} {self.token_value}"


class TokenIssuer(typing.Protocol):

    async def issue_token(self) -> TokenData:
        ...


class TokenManager:

    def __init__(
        self,
        token_issuer: TokenIssuer,
        in_queue: asyncio.Queue,
        out_queue: asyncio.Queue
    ):
        self._token_issuer = token_issuer
        self._in_queue = in_queue
        self._out_queue = out_queue

        self._token = Token({"access_token": "", "expires_in": 0, "token_type": ""})

    async def get_token(self) -> Token:
        if self._token.expired():
            await self._in_queue.put(None)
            await self._out_queue.get()
        return self._token

    async def handler(self):
        while True:
            await self._in_queue.get()
            if self._token.expired():
                self._token = Token(await self._token_issuer.issue_token())
            await self._out_queue.put(None)


class RNDTokenIssuer:

    async def issue_token(self) -> TokenData:
        print("Issuing new token")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return {
            "access_token": "".join(
                [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10)]
            ),
            "expires_in": 10,
            "token_type": "Bearer"
        }


token_manager = TokenManager(RNDTokenIssuer(), asyncio.Queue(), asyncio.Queue())


async def route():
    token = await token_manager.get_token()
    print(f"Sending request with header Authorization: {token}")



async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(token_manager.handler())
    while True:
        requests = [route() for _ in range(10)]
        print("sending requests")
        await asyncio.gather(*requests)
        print("requests sent")
        await asyncio.sleep(4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```